# Using code in a module which belongs to another one

Tags: node.js

I would like to use some code in a module "A" in a module "B" but i don't know how to do it.

i would like to do:

a.js

```
module.exports = {
  hello : function(){
    alert('helo world');
  }
};
```

b.js

```
module.exports = {
  start : function(){
    alert(A.hello());
  }
};
```

main.js

```
A = require("a");
B = require("b");
B.start();
```

But i get "A is not defined".

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node modules all have their own scope, so you need to `require` `A` in `b.js` too.

```
var A = require('a');
module.exports = {
  start : function(){
    alert(A.hello());
  }
};
```

Comment: You also won't need to `require('a')` in `main.js`, since `main.js` never uses A.